# Copying HTML Tables from Outlook to Excel

Tags: html, vba, outlook, export-to-excel

Have been trying to get Excel VBA to export HTML tables - keep getting a runtime error.
Something similar does work when run in Outlook VBA using: For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

What I want to do is to copy the HTML tables and convert them to Excel tables
From here I will be able to work on the data to extract and convert to an ongoing spreadsheet record

```
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim x As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim Item As MailItem
Dim r As Object
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector


Sub getOrderEmailData()

    ' *************This section cycles through email accounts until it finds "testname@icloud.com" and selects the mailitems in this account inbox ********
    Set myAccounts = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores
    
    For i = 1 To myAccounts.Count
        If myAccounts.Item(i).DisplayName = "testname@icloud.com" Then
            Set myInbox = myAccounts.Item(i).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            Debug.Print myInbox
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If myInbox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' avoid error if no account is chosen

    Set myitems = myInbox.Items 'select the Inbox

    ' show some feedback if no email is found
    If myitems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found. Try another account."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Count = 0
    
    
'*************** This section should copy however many tables are found in the HTML email on Outlook to Excel ***********************
        
   For Each Item In myInbox.Items
       'On Error Resume Next
        Set myInspector = Item.GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor  <<<<-------- Here is where the program fails - "Run time error - The operation failed"
            
            Debug.Print Item.Subject
            If Item.Subject = "Alert from MadeUp Solutions" Then

                deleteSheet ("test")

                    'to get all tables
                    Debug.Print wdDoc.Tables.Count
                    For x = 1 To wdDoc.Tables.Count
                        'Select table range
                        Set r = wdDoc.Tables(x)
                        'Copy and paste next table
                        r.Range.Copy
                        Worksheets("Test").Cells(lRow + 1, 1).Select
                        Worksheets("Test").Paste
                        On Error Resume Next
                        'Find row extent of data in each sheet
                        lRow = Worksheets("Test").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
                    Next x
                
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Are you getting an error on the very first item or only after processign a few of them?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, happens on the first pass

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the `Display` method before getting the Word editor to initialize it:

```
For Each Item In myInbox.Items
    'On Error Resume Next
    Item.Display
    ' ...
    Set myInspector = Item.GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
    ' ...
    Item.Close olSave 
Next
```

It also makes sense to run the code for getting the Word editor instance in the Inspector's `Activate` event to be sure the editor is fully initialized when you try to get its instance.

Comment: Hi Eugene, tried Item.Display - got same error. MS Documentation says The WordEditor property is only valid if the IsWordMail method returns True and the EditorType property is olEditorWord.  - Both ok

Comment: It also makes sense to run the code for getting the Word editor instance in the Inspector's `Activate` event to be sure the editor is fully initialized when you try to get its instance.

Answer (score 0):

If `GetInspector` and Word editor do not work for you, the only option is to read the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property and load it into an instance of the `HTMLDocument` object, which you can then use to extract HTML tables.